# Why are my ASP.Net MVC4 WEBAPI ActionFilter being ignored at runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to use an **ActionFilter** attribute so I can intercept the **OnActionExecuting** event and do a token validation in my web api code... Below is some code stripped of my security things(a pretty boilerplate code that checks if the token is in a database with Entity Framework):

```
public class TokenValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var data = new ActionData();
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("token"))
            {
                using (var context = new GNCCustomers()) 
                {
                    data.GNCToken = context.Tokens.Where(t => t.GNCToken == filterContext.HttpContext.Request["token"]).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (data.GNCToken == null)
                    {
                        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult("MissingOrInvalidToken") ;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                data.HttpVerb = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod;

                foreach (string item in filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString)
                {
                    data.Params.Add(item, filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString[item]);
                }
                data.Path = filterContext.RouteData.Values;

                filterContext.ActionParameters["actionData"] = data;
            }


            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }

    }
```

I just applied it to one action method at my controller like this:

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
    {
    [HttpPost]        
            [TokenValidationFilterAttribute]
            public HttpResponseMessage Create(ActionData actionData)
            {

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }...
```

So, the problem is, if I put a breakpoint in the filter code, at the very first line, we didn't even get the breakpoint hit. I've also add some Debug.Print() stubs to check if is there any problem on my environment... Nothing... The code just don't run.

So, anyone has any clue on how to handle this??? I'm getting insane here checking for an solution and seems that this actionFilters are not so well documented. There is only one page in MSDN and saying nothing more that I've already implemented...

Thanks! I really appreciate any help.

Regards...

Comment: it worked locally on my dev machine only. It worked on IISExpress, and on Azure Compute Emulator very well. But, when published on real azure environment, it just don't work. Check the corrected code with the right inheritance from tpeczek bellow:

http://pastebin.com/CSZeiVA2

My problem is that seems that this code is never called, and, the object parameter "actionData" at the controller method is never filled always returning null... Again, it only happens live on azure, not on local IISExpress neither in Azure Compute Emulator... Any clues anyone?

Thanks again...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most probably you have derived from `System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute` not from `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute`.

The first one is from ASP.NET MVC and the second one is from ASP.NET Web API - you want the second one as you are delivering from `ApiController` (so you are most probably hosting ASP.NET Web API inside ASP.NET MVC application).

Comment: I wish they would prefix classes that have the same names as their MVC counterparts with "Api".

Comment: Awesome! It worked tpeczek! But I strongly agree with Dmitry that this crap should be renamed...

Comment: @DmitryStarosta - That's what namespaces are for.

Comment: @MystereMan, you are correct. But considering that Visual Studio itself as well as the commonly used Resharper plug-in are trying to resolve namespaces for you, it is real easy to make this mistake.